# How do I create a valid shortcut for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, .desktop

I read a lot of topics on this issue here, but there is no answer anywhere.
After installing Eclipse, there is no shortcut.
A have `eclipse.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and in `/usr/share/applications/`  with content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse IDE
Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
Icon=/home/n199a/eclipse/java-2020-06/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/n199a/eclipse/java-2020-06/eclipse/
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
```

But shortcut not displayed anywhere.

If I change *Properties* -> *Permissions* -> '*Allow executing file as program*' (checkbox ON) I get error message

> There was an error launching the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have incomplete value in `Exec` key. `Exec` key require the executable name with its path but you provided only the path. According to [Exec key - Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables)

> The `Exec` key must contain a command line. A command line consists of an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments. The executable program can either be specified with its full path or with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the `$PATH` environment variable used by the desktop environment. The name or path of the executable program may not contain the equal sign ("="). Arguments are separated by a space.

To validate the desktop entry, you can always use [`gtk-launch`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/gtk-launch.1.html). To use, run:

```
gtk-launch desktopEntry.desktop
```

If you get

```
gtk-launch: no such application desktopEntry.desktop
```

you have errors either in `Exec` path or the desktop entry isn't in `/usr/share/applications` or `~/.local/share/applications`.