# Invalid desktop entry file error - midi2input

Tags: .desktop

I decided to use a midi controller for certain tasks, so I've used [midi2input](https://github.com/enetheru/midi2input) for this.

The application compiled with no errors however, when I click on the icon I get:

```
Invalid desktop entry file: '~/.local/share/applications/m2i.desktop
```

These are the contents of the desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Encoding=UTF-8 
Version=1.0 
Type=Application 
Terminal=true 
Exec=/usr/local/bin/ 
Name=Midi2Input 
Icon=/home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png
```

Any ideas?

The png exists.  I've also just altered the Exec line as you suggested and I've also re-built it and it's still giving the same error.

---

Current desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Encoding=UTF-8  
Version=1.0  
Type=Application  
Terminal=false  
Exec=/usr/local/bin/m2i  
Name=midi2input  
DBusActivatable=false  
Icon=/home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png  
StartupNotify=true
```

```
emm@i3:~$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/m2i
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 606864 Jul 21 12:28 /usr/local/bin/m2i
emm@i3:~$ ls -al /home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 emm emm 10010 Jul 22 08:05 /home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png
emm@i3:~$
```

Comment: Does that file exist? If so please share the contents?

Comment: It didn't until I created it.  Here's the contents:[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Exec=/usr/local/bin/
Name=Midi2Input
Icon=/home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png

Comment: Looking at the following it looks like your Exec line is wrong (it should point to the executable, not just a folder): https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/  Also: Does the png file exist? What happens if you re-build & try again?

Comment: Add information essential to solve your question to the question, d not leave into the comments. Use "edit" to edit your question.

Comment: Related: [How do I create a valid shortcut for Eclipse?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1258458/816190)

Comment: Please edit the question again to specify the current contents of the file?

Comment: @Geoff - I've posted the updated contents

Comment: Please see edited answer below, and post feedback.

Answer (score 2):

**You have not specified the full path of the executable.**

You have only put:

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/
```

See the documentation on [Desktop Entry Specification - GNOME Developer](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)

> `Exec`
>
> Program to execute, possibly with arguments. See the [`Exec` key](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables) for
> details on how this key works. The `Exec` key is required if
> `DBusActivatable` is not set to `true`. Even if `DBusActivatable` is `true`,
> `Exec` should be specified for compatibility with implementations that
> do not understand `DBusActivatable`.

Not to be confused with:

> `Name`
>
> Specific name of the application, for example "Mozilla".

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you are launching the `.desktop` file you think.
Use `locate m2i.desktop` (1) to see if there is more than one such file in your system (I am assuming you have an updated `mlocate` database).

Then if you are sure the `Exec` file pointed at is correct, comment lines in the `.desktop` files and try launching `m2i`, until you identify the culprit.
You could use `gtk-launch m2i` (2), see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606021/137608).
You could comment one by one, comment them in bunches (sort of a bisection method), or comment all except for the `Exec` and only one more.
This last form is probably the best.

Please post feedback on commands (1) and (2a), (2b), etc. (one for each line that was left uncommented), and the output of

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/m2i
ls -al /home/emm/midi2input/build/res/icons/hicolor/512x512/apps/m2i-light.png
type m2i
```